# How to include all pictures of site within PhotoSwipe?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I've just set up photoswipe, but my architecture of an existing site doesn't allow me to build the common photoswipe-architecture:

```
https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM
```

My site has a more complex structure with more parent `<div>` tags around the images.

**But I want all images, spread over the site, to be able to be swiped through, as if it would be one big gallery**

How could that be possible?

Comment: Maybe look for alternatives, for example, it would be quite easy accomplished using fancybox (http://fancyboxjs.com)

Comment: @Janis thanks for the recommendation! I had a hard time searching for great alternatives, there are so many old libraries. Fancybox seems to be a usable one, I'll give it a try.